# Finding differences between two folders

Tags: md5

I have two folders which I want to open with the same application. To me, both folders *seem* identical, but to the application, they don't.

First, I used this command to find any differences in the contents of the folders:

```
find folder/ -type f -name * -exec md5 {} + | awk '{print $1}' | sort | md5
```

This command yields the *same* result for both folders. But then, I tried this command:

```
tar c folder/ | md5
```

This command yields *different* output for both folders. The command also takes longer to complete for one folder than for the other.

I'm using Mac OS X Snow Leopard. What is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`tar c` includes the folder name** in it's compression, so unless the folders have the same exact name that will cause a mismatch.

---

**Also remember that** `tar` will try to recover the permissions used on files compressed, that might also cause a mismatch if the folders don't have the same exact permissions, as well as ownership.

To see if permissions/ownership is the same for the two folders use something as the below, piped to `sort | md5` or whatever.

```
find foobar -exec stat -f "%p:%N:%u:%g" {} \;
```

The above will have the folder name "foobar" in the output, you should strip that out, you could use something like this:

```
find foobar -type f -exec stat -f "%N:%p:%u:%g" {} \; | sed 's/^foobar//'
```

---

#### My recommendation

If you just want to see if the contents of files and their corresponding file name matches, use the `diff` utility instead of your own custom written version, as below:

```
diff -r folder1 folder2
```

**Documentation of `diff`**

- [**manpages(5) Mac OS X Developer Tools Manual Page - `diff`**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/manpages.5.html)

Comment: Does `tar` use the full path or only the short path?

Comment: `tar` uses the full relative path specified, `tar c foo/bar` will include `foo/bar` even if the full absolut path is `/tmp/foo/bar` (ie. the `cwd` is `/tmp`).

Comment: How would I find out whether there's a permissions mismatch?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
diff -r folder1 folder2
```

Not sure that's available on Max OS X Snow Leopard, though. That should give you any differences that exist between the folders. `tar`, as the other answers already say, includes the folder name and therefore leads to different checksums.

Comment: It is available. Presumably it failed to detect differences, which is why he went the `md5` route (just guessing though).

Answer (score 0):

`tar` remembers relative directory structure. Specifically, `tar c folder1/` will have `"folder1/"` in its first bytes. `tar c folder2/` will have `"folder2/"` there instead. Try `(cd folder && tar c .) | md5` and see what happens?

Comment: The folder names the same. Or does `tar` use the folder names all the way from `/`?